# Listview with edittext contains textwatcher notify data change

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, textwatcher

**Problem:**

Here is the scenario(Split bill app), where custom `ListView` contains `EditText` with textwatcher attached to it in each row. When I change value in `EditText` on any list item other list items `EditText` value does not change.

Example, `ListView` contains five rows and passing total amount in list adapter. Initially `EditText` values in each row is set to 0.

```
totalAmount = 100;
```

Let's say if I change first rows `EditText` value from 0 to 20, other list items `EditText` value must be set to 20.

Here problem is not in spliting but in textwatcher and updating the model.

Here is the Custom list adapter class.

```
public class CustomBillListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    int totalAmt;
    Context context;
    ArrayList<Integer> amtSplit;

    public CustomBillListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Integer> amtSplit, int totalAmt) {
        this.context = context;
        this.amtSplit = amtSplit;
        this.totalAmt = totalAmt;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return amtSplit.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return amtSplit.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return amtSplit.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null)  {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_custom, null);
        }

        EditText txtAmount = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.amounts);
        txtAmount.setText(amtSplit.get(position).toString());
        txtAmount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                getEqualAmount(s.toString(), position);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    private void getEqualAmount(String sAmt, int pos) {
        if(sAmt != "") {
            int amt = Integer.parseInt(sAmt);
            int len = 5; //hardcoded value, assume that there are 5 list items
            int remainingAmt = totalAmt - amt;
            int shareAmt = remainingAmt / len;
            int c = shareAmt * len;

            amtSplit.clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if (pos == i) {
                    amtSplit.add(amt);
                } else {
                    amtSplit.add(shareAmt);
                }
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Activity Class:

```
public class TestTwo extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
{
    ListView view;
    CustomBillListAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Integer> amtList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_two);

        LinearLayout addContacts = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.add_contact);
        addContacts.setOnClickListener(this);

        view = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomBillListAdapter(TestTwo.this, amtList, 100);
        view.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void pickContact()
    {
        amtList.add(0);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        pickContact();
    }
}
```

I am trying to implement this feature which is in "SettleUp" app.
Logs:

```
01-19 00:38:13.308 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype V/TextView: stopSelectionActionMode()
01-19 00:38:13.309 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype V/InputMethodManager: START INPUT: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{56dbaa8 VFED..CL .F....I. 8,8-532,70 #7f0d007c app:id/amounts} ic=com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection@c778c6b tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@17193c8 controlFlags=#0
01-19 00:38:13.312 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype V/TextView: stopSelectionActionMode()
01-19 00:38:13.316 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype V/TextView: stopSelectionActionMode()
01-19 00:38:13.317 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype D/ListView: mSelectorRect.setEmpty in layoutChildren this=android.widget.ListView{94612c7 VFED.VC. ......ID 0,134-540,291 #7f0d0071 app:id/list}
01-19 00:38:13.320 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
01-19 00:38:13.322 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
01-19 00:38:13.323 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
01-19 00:38:13.353 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype D/ListView: measureHeightOfChildren adapter = com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype.adapter.TestListAdapter@38d3801d, startPosition = 0, endPosition = 1, maxHeight = 370, this = android.widget.ListView{94612c7 VFED.VC. ......I. 0,134-540,291 #7f0d0071 app:id/list}
01-19 00:38:13.356 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype V/TextView: stopSelectionActionMode()
01-19 00:38:13.356 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype V/TextView: stopSelectionActionMode()
01-19 00:38:13.356 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype V/TextView: stopSelectionActionMode()
01-19 00:38:13.356 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype V/TextView: stopSelectionActionMode()
01-19 00:38:13.356 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype V/TextView: stopSelectionActionMode()
01-19 00:38:13.357 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype V/TextView: stopSelectionActionMode()
01-19 00:38:13.357 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype V/TextView: stopSelectionActionMode()
01-19 00:38:13.358 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype V/TextView: stopSelectionActionMode()
01-19 00:38:13.358 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype V/TextView: stopSelectionActionMode()
01-19 00:38:13.359 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype V/TextView: stopSelectionActionMode()
01-19 00:38:13.359 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype V/TextView: stopSelectionActionMode()
01-19 00:38:13.359 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype V/TextView: stopSelectionActionMode()
01-19 00:38:13.359 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype V/TextView: stopSelectionActionMode()
01-19 00:38:13.360 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype V/TextView: stopSelectionActionMode()
01-19 00:38:13.360 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype V/TextView: stopSelectionActionMode()
01-19 00:38:13.361 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype V/TextView: stopSelectionActionMode()
01-19 00:38:13.362 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype V/InputMethodManager: START INPUT: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{56dbaa8 VFED..CL .F....I. 8,8-532,70 #7f0d007c app:id/amounts} ic=com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection@20130d9d tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@1ab0d212 controlFlags=#0
01-19 00:38:13.372 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype V/TextView: stopSelectionActionMode()
01-19 00:38:13.378 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype V/TextView: stopSelectionActionMode()
01-19 00:38:13.378 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype D/ListView: mSelectorRect.setEmpty in layoutChildren this=android.widget.ListView{94612c7 VFED.VC. ......ID 0,134-540,291 #7f0d0071 app:id/list}
01-19 00:38:13.383 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
01-19 00:38:13.390 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype D/ActivityThread: ACT-AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED ActivityRecord{28d782da token=android.os.BinderProxy@1c3d530b {com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype.TestTwo}}
01-19 00:38:13.413 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype D/ActivityThread: ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@1c3d530b
01-19 00:38:13.413 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
01-19 00:38:13.417 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
01-19 00:38:13.429 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype V/TextView: stopSelectionActionMode()
01-19 00:38:13.429 19367-19367/com.splitbill.kurukshetran.splitbillprototype D/AbsListView: onWindowFocusChanged: hasWindowFocus=false, this=android.widget.ListView{94612c7 VFED.VC. ........ 0,134-540,291 #7f0d0071 app:id/list}
```

Comment: I created a project in Android Studio, literally copied and pasted this code into the adapter, and it all worked fine for me. Can you post your Activity and the layout file, as well as the layout for the list item row.

Comment: I cannot able to edit text due to calling notifyDataSetChanged, it crashes the keyboard. Also  notifyDataSetChanged crashes the app.

Comment: So every time you go to type into the edit text, what happens? It won't let you type? Please post your layout file that contains your `ListView`.  Make sure your ListView has `android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"`

Comment: Ya my list contains android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants". When i click on edittext to edit value app stucks and android monitor repeatedly logs the message as above.